# InstallShield 2013 SQLServerSelectLogin screen doesn't populate

Tags: installscript-msi, installshield-2013

I've inherited an InstallShield 2013 InstallScript MSI project that installs our product and I'm really new to IS. I've figured out the basics and even created an new project, but this has me baffled. One of our installers uses SQLServerSelectLogin (or at least I assume that it does) to get the user to select a SQL server to install to, and just recently it stopped populating with the list of installed servers and I need to figure out why.

I've rolled back just about all of the changes that have been made since this started being an issue and it's still happening. (The changes that I haven't rolled back are really minor and shouldn't effect the install). Being new to IS I really don't even know where to look for this to debug it. So my questions are:

1. Where would I find the code that populates this list?
2. How can I debug an install to figure out what's not happening?

Answer (score 0):

I found an obscure [post](http://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?206473-Get-SQL-Connections-list-problem) that describes three files that need to be downloaded and installed. Doing this fixed the problem.